# Ionic 3 - innerHtml is not loading images on android

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic3

I am fetching some data from a WordPress website. Which needs to be displayd in the app. All HTML is loading. But the images are not loading. I have tested it on many android devices. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="post-details" [class]="'post-details-'+post.id" [innerHtml]="post.post_content | safe"></div>
```

**SafePipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
    name: 'safe'
})

export class SafePipe {

constructor(protected _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {

}

public transform(value: string, type: string = 'html'): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
        case 'html': return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
        case 'style': return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
        case 'script': return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
        case 'url': return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
        case 'resourceUrl': return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
        default: throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? Are you using a content security policy? Have you tried displaying the images without the SafePipe?

Comment: There is no error in the console. It is working on the browser. But not working on mobile devices.